# Get model class from symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, symbols

I'm implementing a method, that will be used in many places of a project.

```
def do association

end
```

"association" is a symbol, like `:articles`, `:tags`, `:users` etc.

When the association is `:articles`, I need to work with the Article model.

When the association is `:users`, I need to work with the User model.

Etc.

I know, that I can write a helper method, that returns model class, depending on the provided symbol. But is there a ready to use method for that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Rails provides a method called `classify` on the `String` class for such purpose.

```
:users.to_s.classify.constantize
#User

:line_items.to_s.classify.constantize
#LineItem
```

**Edit:**

If you are trying to retrieve the class associated with an association, use this approach:

```
Author.reflect_on_association(:books).klass
# => Book
```

This will address the scenario where the association name doesn't match the class name.

E.g:

```
class Order
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :active_line_items, :class_name => "LineItem", 
             :conditions => {:deleted => false}
end
```

In the example above, `:active_line_items` will result in `ActiveLineItem` and our original code will throw error.

Read more about this [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Reflection/AssociationReflection/klass).

Comment: You should also have a look at the `#safe_constantize` variant, which does basically the same as `#constanzize`, but doesn't raise a NameError if the class could not be found. Instead it returns `nil`. This turns out to be a little more handy than with exception. For instance: `model_name.to_s.classify.safe_constantize || Event`

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
(:users.to_s.singularize.capitalize.constantize).find :all, :conditions => ["name = ?", "john"]
```

And with your example

```
association.to_s.singularize.capitalize.constantize
```

Comment: This solution will not work when the class name has two parts, Eg: `:order_details` will result in `Order_detail` rather than `OrderDetail`.